# Is there a way to flush DNS cache on Android?

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, dns

I'd like to flush DNS in my Android app due to some external event.
I've noticed that Android system code uses something like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLEAR_DNS_CACHE);
```

to clear DNS cache but it doesn't appear to be available in the user code.
Are there any alternatives?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**This may work only if your Android is rooted**

Using the adb tool you can clear cache like that (tested on the current Android x86 image)

```
os.system(f'adb -s {host} shell am force-stop com.android.chrome')
os.system(f'adb -s {host} shell ndc resolver clearnetdns wlan0')
os.system(f'adb -s {host} shell ndc resolver clearnetdns wifi_eth')
```

So, if your android is rooted, you could try to execute the same commands (without `adb -s ... shell`) prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Manually you can Open Chrome and type

chrome://net-internals/#dns

This will take you to the DNS lookup page where you will find a "Clear host cache" putton, push it.